# Base64 decode returns null in test environment

Tags: android, unit-testing, base64

I am trying to run Unit Tests on my code, and one test fails, when I got deeper I notice that `Base64.decode()` always return **null** in test environment. My specific case is:

The method to test

```
public String decode(String jwt){
    System.out.println(jwt); //eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(jwt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(data, "UTF-8"); //null pointer exception - data = null
}
```

Test itself:

```
@Test
public void validateBase64Decode() {
    String stringToTest = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9";
    String expectedResult = "{\"sub\": \"1234567890\", \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"admin\": true}";
    Assert.assertEquals(Util.decode(stringToTest), expectedResult);
}
```

The test always fails due to null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:481)
```

Thus I went further and found that any String in test environment cannot be decoded:

```
  @Test
  public void validateBase64Decode() {
         Assert.assertNotNull(Base64.decode("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9", 0));     
} //Test NEVER passes - assertion error
```

Please, any guru here? What is wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course "anyString" cannot be base64 decoded. As it is not base64 encoded. You should give a better example that fails.

Comment: Give an example where you start with data that you encode. Then decode that and compare with original data.

Comment: If you want to use it for json web tokens there are some libraries that does the job.

Comment: @greenapps see the update. The encoded String is correct now.

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp it was just taken for example. The problem is in Base64 decode

Comment: Just chiming in to say this is happening to me as well. :(

Comment: @rjfellman, apparently Android SDK uses its own implementation of Base64 library thus it can only be tested via Instrumentational tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mockk, you can intercept the calls and fulfil them with java.util.Base64 instead. This code ignores the flags but you get the idea.

```
    mockkStatic(android.util.Base64::class)
    val b64Encoded = slot<String>()
    val flags = slot<Int>()
    every { android.util.Base64.decode(capture(b64Encoded), capture(flags)) } coAnswers {
        java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(this.args[0] as String)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with robotium and its working:

```
public void testValidateBase64Decode() throws InterruptedException {
    assertTrue("EcoScoreTesterActivity Activity never started", solo.waitForActivity(MainMenuActivity.class, WAIT_FOR_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT));
    String stringToTest = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9";
    String expectedResult = "{\"sub\": \"1234567890\", \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"admin\": true}";
    //The string decode is different as yours
    expectedResult = "{\"sub\":\"1234567890\",\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"admin\":true}";

    assertNotNull(Base64.decode(stringToTest, 0));
    String result = new String(Base64.decode(stringToTest, 0));
    //Show in logcat result of decoding 
    Log.i("Test-Decoding","result+":result);
    assertTrue("Error decoding", result.equals(expectedResult));
}
```

In you case It should be in this way:

```
public void testvalidateBase64Decode() {
    String stringToTest = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9";
    String expectedResult = "{\"sub\": \"1234567890\", \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"admin\": true}";
    //The string decode is different as yours
    expectedResult = "{\"sub\":\"1234567890\",\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"admin\":true}";
    String result = new String(Base64.decode(stringToTest, 0));
    //Show in logcat result of decoding 
    Log.i("Test-Decoding","result+":result);
    Assert.assertTrue("Error decoding", result.equals(expectedResult));
}
```

I just check both options and It's working in my workspace

Comment: I don't use robotium. Your test is fails in my environment on same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I use PowerMockito

Comment: I guess the unit test does not have access to android.util.Base64 class and hence returns null. Check this link: tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support. I think you shouId write it as an instrumentation test instead. Using for example robotium.

Comment: It should work in local unit tests, there is no reason it need Android Framework to work

Comment: Here you can see differences between unit test and instumentation test. https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html

Comment: I know the differences well. Thus I say there is no reason it needs Android Framework to work!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in gradle compile group: `'commons-codec'`, name: `'commons-codec'`, version: `'1.9'`
    And use this methods by importing

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
new String(Base64.encodeBase64(inData))
Base64.decodeBase64(inString.getBytes())
```